# ostream function seemingly not producing error message properly

Tags: c++

so I'm using an online grading tool to check my code for this method, and the error shown below keeps getting displayed:

> In runAudit, if the input file does NOT exist or the output file already EXISTS, the program should not try to process the input file. It should, instead, produce an error message.

However, in my extensive testing, my function does produce the error messages as anticipated. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

```cpp
void runAudit(istream& inputRead, ostream& outputWrite) {
    string fileName;
    string outputFileName;
    outputWrite << "Enter the input file name: \n";
    inputRead >> fileName;
    if (fileExists(fileName) == 1) {
        outputWrite << "Enter the output file name: \n";
        inputRead >> outputFileName;
        if (fileExists(outputFileName) == 1) {
            outputWrite << "Error: Output file was found. \n";
        }
        else {
            //this is the "processing files" function mentioned in the prompt
            processFiles(fileName, outputFileName);
        }
    }
    else if (fileExists(fileName) == 0) {
        outputWrite << "Input file not found. \n";
    }
}
```

**Edit**: forgot to add the `fileExists()` method. I have included it below:

```cpp
bool fileExists(string fileName) {
    ifstream streamOne;
    streamOne.open(fileName);
    return !streamOne.fail();
}
```

Comment: [If your compiler is relatively up-to-date](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

Comment: You are opening a file to test for its existence. If the file actually exists, but you don't have permission to open it, you report the file does not exist. Consider using a different way to test for existence, such as `stat()` or `std::filesystem::exists()`. Also, you are calling `fileExists()` multiple times for the input file, which is redundant.  And why are you comparing booleans to integers?

Comment: I do agree with is a bad way to test for existence -- the prompt for this project dictates we do it this way though, so nothing I can do about it there. Calling fileExists multiple times is redundant though -- I will fix that

Comment: testing for file exists can be tricky, for example if UNC paths are used on windows. In that case I use file-open, stat and windows specific unctions like ::GetFileAttributes to find out if the file really does not exist.